# VBA - Filter shown cells based on inputted password

Tags: vba, excel

I am (trying) creating a VBA code that filters Sheet1 based on the inputted password. I have an excel file with 2 Sheets and sheet2 has the passwords in Column B and the "filter" in column A. I will distribute the excel file and give the corresponding password to the parties and when they input their password all the info from other parties will be deleted.
The code:

```
Sub Open_with_password()

pas = Application.InputBox("Input password")
If pas = False Or pas = "" Then Exit Sub
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

a = 0
For i = 1 To Sheet2.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row
    If Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(i, 2) = pas Then
        c = Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(i, 1) 'the agency corresponding with the password
        a = a + 1
    End If
Next
'Check for password
If a = 0 Then
    MsgBox "Wrong password. Report can not be accessed"
    ActiveWorkbook.Close False

        Sheet2.Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden
        Sheet1.Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden

    Exit Sub
    'If correct password
Else:
        Sheet1.Visible = xlSheetVisible

        Worksheets("Sheet1").Select
        Worksheets("Sheet1").Unprotect Password = "XYZ"

        On Error Resume Next
        ActiveSheet.ShowAllData
        On Error GoTo 0

   'Filter according to input password
        If c <> "Admin" Then ActiveSheet.Range("$A$2:$AQ$500000").AutoFilter Field:=17, Criteria1:=c
        Set rCell = ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Range.Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells(1, 1)
        Rows(rCell.Row).Select
        Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Copy
        Worksheets("Sheet1").Select
        Range("A2").Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, _
        Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
        Range("A2").Select
   'If Admin
        If c = "Admin" Then
        Sheet2.Visible = xlSheetVisible
        Sheet1.Visible = xlSheetVisible
        End If

End If

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

The issues I've encountered so far are:
  1. When I open the file, the input box doesn't automatically show, ideally it would show while the user sees nothing.
  2. When it filters according to the password (The filter works) when it reaches the part where it's suppose to delete everything else, it doesn't. I am using a copy and paste method and an error pops (Error 1004)

Much appreciated for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suggestions:

When the workbook opens call your macro.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Open_with_password
End Sub
```

I would keep your data intact on a hidden worksheet.

> Sheet1.Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden

Copy the filtered cells to a different worksheet

```
Set rCell = ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
rcell.Copy Sheet2.Range("A1")
```

When the workbook closes clear Sheet2.

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    Sheet2.Cells.ClearContents
End Sub
```

If you do it this way you users won't be able to access the hidden data when they open the workbook without enabling macros.

Answer (score 0):

1.Code should be on the `Workbook_Open()` event, you may do a call for another sub -my suggestion-. In "ThisWorkbook" object:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Call Open_with_password
End Sub
```

2. If you are using copy-paste, you can't do a select in the middle, doing so will lost the clipboard (normal behavior in excel VBA), hence you will having nothing to paste for, thus the error.

```
Rows(rCell.Row).Select
        Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Copy
        Worksheets("Sheet1").Select
        Range("A2").Select 'lost clipboard
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, _
        Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
        Range("A2").Select
```

Change for

```
Rows(rCell.Row).Select
        Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Copy
        Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        Excel.Application.CutCopyMode = False 'clears clipboard
```

**EDIT:**
[image]

It should work no matter if there are filters or not.

OT: Next step for you would be searching how to avoid select (this is so much time consuming).

Comment: Thanks for your help @Sgdva your answer solves the password part. I forgot to it as "Private". Howver it still gives me error 1004 in the following line: `Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues,`  
It selects all the rows I want but then doesn't paste them & deletes the others as it says the copy& paste area cannot overlap

Comment: I don't use `Selection.PasteSpecial` Did you try the code exactly as posted? Area overlap, do you have merged cells?

Comment: I copied exactly what you gave me and it doesn't copy on top of the other data. Maybe due to the filter...

Comment: As you may see in my edited response, the code should work with filters or not. I can't replicate your issue, as suggested by @Thomas I missed the visibile type, you should try that before setting the range

Answer (score 0):

I am answering my own question as I used the following solution and it seems to be working:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Call Open_with_password
End Sub
```

&

```
Sub Open_with_password()
        Sheet2.Visible = xlSheetHidden
        Sheet1.Visible = xlSheetHidden
        Sheet3.Cells.ClearContents
        Sheet1.Range("A1", "AQ1").Copy
        Sheet3.Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
pas = Application.InputBox("Input password")


If pas = False Or pas = "" Then Exit Sub

a = 0
For i = 1 To Sheet2.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row
    If Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(i, 2) = pas Then
        c = Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(i, 1) 'the agency corresponding with the password
        a = a + 1
    End If
Next
'Check for password
If a = 0 Then
    MsgBox "Wrong password. Report can not be accessed"
    ActiveWorkbook.Close False

        Sheet2.Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden
        Sheet1.Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden

    Exit Sub
    'If correct password
Else:
        Sheet1.Visible = xlSheetVisible

        Worksheets("Sheet1").Select
        Worksheets("Sheet1").Unprotect Password = "amazon"

        On Error Resume Next
        ActiveSheet.ShowAllData
        On Error GoTo 0

   'Filter according to input password
        If c <> "Admin" Then ActiveSheet.Range("$A$2:$AQ$500000").AutoFilter Field:=17, Criteria1:=c
        Set rCell = ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Range.Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells(1, 1)
       Rows(rCell.Row).Select
        Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Copy
        Sheets("Sheet3").Range("A2").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        Excel.Application.CutCopyMode = False 'clears clipboard
        Sheet1.Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden
   'If Admin
        If c = "Admin" Then
        Sheet2.Visible = xlSheetVisible
        Sheet1.Visible = xlSheetVisible
        End If

End If

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```